# Align image with bottom of frame (beamer)

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have 3 images that are supposed to appear "replacing" each other on a beamer frame. I've been able to do that with `overprint` and `onslide` with no trouble. The problem is that one of the images is taller than the rest, so it appears shifted from the others. Since an image is better than a thousand words, I will illustrate what I mean bellow. The code is:

```
\begin{frame}{Problem description}
\begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/img_1.png}
    \onslide<2>\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/img_2.png}
    \onslide<3>\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figs/img_3.png}
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
```

And my images are the ones below:

[image: First image]
[image: Second image, which aligns perfectly with the previous one]
[image: Third image, which does not align because it is a little bit taller than the previous 2]

The third image does not align because it is a little bit taller than the previous 2.

I believe that if I align the images using their bottom, I might get the "effect" of superposition that I want. Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple hack, you could use the tallest image in a `\vphantom` to make sure all your slides have the same height.

However the vertical alignment isn't your only problem: your last image is also wider.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Problem description}

\hfill\vphantom{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img_3}}%
\includegraphics<1>[scale=0.3]{img_1}%
\includegraphics<2>[scale=0.3]{img_2}%
\includegraphics<3>[scale=0.3]{img_3}%
\hspace{3cm}

\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use a bottom aligned frame (it looks a bit empty like this, but maybe your real frame has more content):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[b]
\frametitle{Problem description}

\hfill
\includegraphics<1>[scale=0.3]{img_1}%
\includegraphics<2>[scale=0.3]{img_2}%
\includegraphics<3>[scale=0.3]{img_3}%
\hspace{3cm}

\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first solution definately worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: @EduardoAlvesdaSilva You're welcome!